# What is the term in music recording for a mistake that is intentionally left in?

Tags: terminology, recording

The original fuzz bass effect, in "Don't Worry" by Robbins, for example, is one of these. Another example would be a click track being audible within the song; this I have also heard. "Lo-fi music" is music that lives on allowing such mistakes to persist, but more granularly, what do you call a mistake that is so allowed?

Comment: I'd say "double mistake": the first is playing it, the second leaving it there ;-)

Comment: I call it "live performance". :-)

Comment: Related: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f19Z9Y0U92A

Comment: Permitted cock-up.

Comment: Half of Led Zeppelin's Whole Lot of Love would be a famous example. You can hear the original vocal take bleeding off the drum mics. Left in because… what the hell else were you going to do to clean that up in 1970? Or Bowie's "Get back on there" in Jean Genie - when the band almost went to the chorus 2 bars early.

Comment: Improvisation, ornamentation, innovation.

Comment: @Tetsujin I gotta admit, I started asking this question because I forgot the word "bleed."

Comment: I always called it “leaving a mistake in”

Comment: I would call it owning your mistake

Comment: Another famous example was Its only rock n roll by the Rolling Stones, recorded it just to find out they recorded it in completely the wrong key

Comment: "lo fi" means low fidelity. That style tries to deliberately have lots on recording noise. To my ears it tries to recreate the sound of low quality, at home recording to tape, like old four track recording on cassette tapes, etc.

Comment: A fairly extreme example: when Tangerine Dream were recording a track from [Force Majeure](http://www.voices-in-the-net.de/force_majeure.htm), a transistor blew on their mixing desk — but they liked the resulting distortion and strange noises enough to keep it all in.

Answer (score 4):

An excerpt from the wikipedia page on the [Traveling Wilburys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traveling_Wilburys), a rock "supergroup" of sorts:

> The term "Wilbury" also originated during the Cloud Nine sessions. Referring to recording errors created by faulty equipment, Harrison jokingly remarked to Lynne, "We'll bury 'em in the mix." Thereafter, they used the term for any small error in performance. Harrison first suggested "the Trembling Wilburys" as the group's name; at Lynne's suggestion, they amended it to "Traveling Wilburys"

Hardly well accepted terminology, but a word for it nonetheless.

Answer (score 3):

Not limited specifically to music or recording, a happy accident might be called [serendipity](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/serendipity).

Several things that end up as effects in recording started out as [epiphenomena](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epiphenomenon), e.g., a lot of what we have come to expect in guitar tone came about because the process of sensing and amplifying the sound was imperfect.

But those are not "mistakes" exactly.

The [Wikipedia article on "Don't Worry"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_Worry_(Marty_Robbins_song)) says that guitarist Grady Martin didn't like the sound (so at least he considered it a mistake), but the producer liked the effect and kept it.

In your example of the audible click track, do you know that the artist or producer perceived it as a mistake?  It could have been done intentionally (or at least deliberately).

Some "lo fi" might arise from accepting mistakes, but some might just arise from experimentation by someone with an artistic ear and a willingness to eschew conventional recording or performance wisdom.

I've not yet come across a good concise musical term for a note played accidentally during improvisation that ends up working out.  We need one.

A related question was posed on the English Language & Usage stack: [What is it called when something you previously took to be a mistake turned out to be the correct decision?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/214935/344516)

You might also look into what some call "Persian flaws", [deliberate mistakes in handmade Persian rugs and carpets](http://www.orientalrugexperts.com/deliberate-mistakes-in-handmade-persian-rugs-and-carpets/).  (Similar concepts occur [elsewhere in the arts](https://www.amusingplanet.com/2017/08/the-art-of-deliberate-imperfection.html).)

Comment: "I've not yet come across a good concise musical term for a note played accidentally during improvisation that ends up working out. We need one." It's called Jazz :P

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps 'happy accident' is the term you're looking for.  But sometimes just 'accident' that it wasn't feasible (or wasn't considered worth the effort) to fix.  I imagine most click-track leakage falls into this category.